# bash completion for certain types of files in a special directory

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a list of unison profiles which exists in `~/.unison/*.prf`.

I'd like to have bash completion so that when I type `unison` or `unison-gtk` and hit tab it would list the `.prf` files from that folder without the `.prf` part.

Perhaps an example would be clearer:

```
$ ls ~/.unison/*.prf
default.prf dot-mozilla.prf to-desktop.prf

$ cd  ~  # just to show you don't have to be in the ~/.unison folder
$ unison to<tab>
$ unison to-desktop
```

I foresee needing this for another tool as well, so it would be convenient if there were parts that could be reused.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are running debian/ubuntu or possibly other GNU/Linux distros, there should be examples of this type of completion in your /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory. Here is an example of how you might set up a completion script for unison:

```
have unison &&
_unison_show()
{
        local cur

        COMPREPLY=()
        cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$(for x in ~/.unison/*.prf; do echo $(basename ${x%.prf}); done)" -- $cur ) )
}
complete -F _unison_show unison
```

Comment: Works great, the only changes I did was
    complete -o nospace -F _unison_show unison unison-gtk